# Looping a function and saving outputs

Tags: python

I'm playing with a minimum conflicts N-Queens solver and would like to loop the function to get all possible configurations and then save them and say how many  configurations were found. The main function is shown below.

Edit: Apologies, I'm using a solver I found [here](https://github.com/calcelli/Min-Conflict-nQueens/blob/master/QueenSolver.py).  It will give me one solution but I want all possible ones and an unsure how to do that without repeating solutions

The `eightQueen.initialize_board()` generates a random initial configuration and the `main` function gives me the number of moves required to solve this configuration.

I want to loop through all possible initial configurations and print the number of moves for each of them.

```
def main():
    # Create a new instance of the minConflict class
    random.seed(datetime.now())

    number_of_rows = input("How many rows are on the board?")
    eightQueen = minConflict(number_of_rows)



    # Assigns the queens to their initial positions on the board then prints it
    eightQueen.initialize_board()
    eightQueen.print_board()

    #solves the given board and then prints it and the number of moves it had to take
    num_of_moves = eightQueen.solve_board()
    eightQueen.print_board()
    print ("It took", num_of_moves, "moves to solve this board")




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Great job so far, and what is the question?

Comment: Are you asking how to save something? What? Are you using a library too or some other code? It's not clear from what you have posted.

Comment: If you want to save python run time objects.  Please use pickle or shelve for the same.

Comment: Apologies, I'm using a solver I found here: https://github.com/calcelli/Min-Conflict-nQueens/blob/master/QueenSolver.py It will give me one solution but I want all possible ones and an unsure how to do that without repeating solutions